# My Split access database makes query Changes for other users

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have slit my access Database into a FE(front End) and BE(Back End).

Each user has their own copy of the FE and linked tables to their BE.  When user A Filters their form, that filter affect all the other users.

There is no record level locking.

The Database FE's are all set to Shared on the open mode

I need to stop this from happening.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A frontend cannot modify a frontend on another machine, so something else is going on.

Comment: It looks like the FE is modifying the table that has the control for my combo field.  I did not think that access was altering the actual table but it is.  I change the combo box to a query and that fixed the problem.   Though i can not explain why it happened int he first place.